# Create dict from tuples, with tuple variable names as keys in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

Python 2.7

Hello. I have some tuples I would like to make into a dict that uses variable_name:tuple as the key:value pair in the dict.

For example, I have the following tuples I would like to consolidate into a single dict.

tuples:

```
a = (1,2)
b = (3,4)
c = (5,6)
d = (7,8)
```

dict:

```
results = {'a':a, 'b':b, 'c':c, 'd':d}
```

Is there a simpler way to create a dict from tuples that automatically uses the tuple variable names as keys, and tuples as values? (**I know I can just write a function**, not looking for that solution). I was hoping it would just be something like:

```
results = {a,b,c,d}
```

or, less desirably

```
results = some_module_function(a,b,c,d)
```

Comment: Generally using the names of variables as strings in your code requires some hackey approach. It is a sign you are doing something wrong, generally.

Comment: For example, if you had nothing else definined in the global scope, you could use something like: `{k:v for k,v in globals().items() if not k.startswith('_')}`... but you will quickly run into problems.

Comment: Why did you define them as individual variables rather than a dictionary in the first place? Just make it a dictionary from the start.

Comment: A tuple could be referred to by multiple variable names; no one of them would have any particular claim to being "the" name of the tuple.  Likewise, a tuple could exist (as an element of some other object, perhaps) without any variable name referring to it.

Comment: Okay, yeah I thought that might be the case. Could not think of any other time a built_in or module function used/converted variable or function names to strings. Thank you.

Comment: I don't want to encourage this too much, but {n:v for n, v in locals().items() if isinstance(v, tuple)} maybe? Your first example in the OP was better because you just take the exact names you know you want.

Answer (score 1):

Similar to the global scope suggestion, you could use locals():

```
myDict = {}
myDict.update({k:v for k,v in locals().copy().iteritems() if k[:2] != '__' and k != 'myDict'})
```